# How to get the relation between user in my app?

Tags: django, algorithm, model

Suppose there is family, each family member can login to my app, when the user login, I want to show the relation between him and the other family member instead of just the family member name.

the real challenge is the relation is dynamic according to the login user, for example:

```
 A is the father of B
 C is the wife of B
 B and C have a child D
```

if D login the relation will be

```
 A = granddad
 B = father
 C = mother
 D = me
```

but if A log in , the relation will be

```
 A = me
 B = son
 C = daughter in law
 D = grandson
```

the example is fairly simple but the real world situation is much more complicated, like borther and sister, aunt,uncle etc.

Am using django and this is how my model is defined:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   family = models.ManyToManyField(FamilyProfile,related_name='family_members')
   realname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField(
    'user born date', null=True, blank=True)
   is_male = models.BooleanField(default=False) # True male

   relation_level = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False,default=9999)
   is_foreign = models.BooleanField(default=False) # True foreign
   is_host = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # Ture host,
   objects = profileManager()
```

because the relation ship is dynamic , I can't save it to the database, instead, I use the profileManager to calculate the relation ship and add it to the member: member.relation_name, but this is too complicated for me, right now I'm using a lot of if...else statement and its really long, and really stupid, so please help me with this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at it from a DB point-of-view the correct way to do this is to add an 'id' field to the UserProfile model, and also add another class like:

class Relations(models.Model):
   relation_id = models.IntegerField()
   relation_name = models.CharField()

which would be filled with the relations (like: (1, "son of"), (2, "father of"), etc..) (you might also need to make one string for male and one for female. That's the least interesting point here.

After you've created this list of Relations you need to assign the relations to users, and therefore we make another model:

class UserToRelations(models.Model):
   user_a_id = models.IntegerField()
   user_b_id = models.IntegerField()
   relation_id = models.IntegerField()

[You might just do that with the `key`s, I really don't remember django that well]

So now you need to populate the `UserToRelations` table just each time you add a member to the DB. You calculate the relationships there.

The selecting part is where you see the profit of this. Every time a member logs in, you just need to get all the relevant rows from the `UserToRelations` model and you just present them.

Comment: I just tried this method, I think It should work, but compared to algorithm which one is better?

Comment: Well, in a design point-of-view my answer is the way to go. Algorithm-wise you should use the same algorithm you use right now, but not calculating this every time a user logs in, but just when he's added to your DB